# SQLite3 Ghost table

Tags: sqlite, missing-data, ghost

So I've gotten back in to working on a hobby project and when opening up the SQLite DB the table returns nothing... but the table is there if you look at the file in Notepad++. The file has just sat on my hard drive for a few weeks, so what's happen to it? Is there a way to fix this? Attached is a link to an image(since I can't embed it directly) - [Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRdhh.png)

Comment: Looks like data of deleted rows.

Comment: could you show the command you use to open the db with sqlite? Are you sure you are opening the correct db file? Try to do the `.tables` sqlite command once you connect to your db to inspect the table names.